# Create particular Json structure and save it to external memory

Tags: android, json

I know this topic has already been discussed but I have a dual problem, which I have not found an answer on other pages, related to JSon files, in Android application:

1) know what is the best procedure to save a file on the external memory, using an ArrayList that contains a lot of data.
From this ArrayList, I extract individual data, like this (NOTE: this code is used now from me to write in a text file, not in a Json):

```
File file     = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "FileName.txt");
FileWriter  f = null;
PrintWriter p = null;
f = new FileWriter(file, false);
p = new PrintWriter(f);
[...]
for(int i=0; i<arrayList.size();  i++){
    p.println(arrayList.get(0);
    arrayList.remove(0);
}
[...]
p.close();
f.close();
```

I want to use the same procedure (arrayList), to create a Json file on external memory.

2) I can not create a Json file with this PARTICULAR STRUCTURE. I'd like to have an array (of individual items) inside another array (the elements of "number_A"), i.e.:

```
{
    "begin": 1753,
    "end": 11941,
    "number_A": [
        [1805],
        [5156],
        [8592]
    ]
}
```

I can only create a structure like this:

```
 {
        "begin": 1753,
        "end": 11941,
        "number_A": [
            1805,
            5156,
            8592
        ]
    }
```

Can someone give me some suggestions?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: what is your code to create json object?

Comment: instead putting int(fx: `1805`) into `number_A` JSONArray put int array `int[] {1805}` ...

Comment: I tried a lot of combination to have this particular structure, but I haven't found a good one. When it will be possible for me, i will try this other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather simple. Something like

```
private void createjson() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("begin", 1753);
        json.put("end", 11941);
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        array.put(new JSONArray().put(1805));
        array.put(new JSONArray().put(5156));
        array.put(new JSONArray().put(8592));
        json.put("number_A", array);
    }
```

Will give you `{"number_A":[[1805],[5156],[8592]],"end":11941,"begin":1753}`

Comment: Thank you for your time.. I'll try this one on my App! ;)

Comment: this solution works perfectly! Thank you for your time and sorry if I can not give my vote to your answer, but does not have enough "experience points."

Answer (score 0):

Alright, you need to do this,

Step 1: import google gson library [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Step 2: define a class structure for your json, in above case this will be structure preferably

```
 Class Data{
    int begin;
    int end;
    int[] number_A;
}
```

Step 3: As you said you have array list, so i assume it to be like this `ArrayList<Data>`
        once you have array list, call this method to get json string representation of your calss like this.

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(your array list object here);
```

by now we are ready to put this data into file system, for doing that use this.

Step 4: Saving data

```
   try{

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(your array list object here);
        FileOutputStream fos = context.
                openFileOutput("YOUR_FILE_NAME_HERE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(json.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Alright bravo, now data is saved, next agenda how to read it when required, it preety simple again.

Step 5: reading json back

```
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput("YOUR_FILE_NAME");
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(fis.getFD());
       TypeToken<List<Data>> token = new TypeToken<List<Data>>() {
       };
       Gson gson = new Gson();
       // your saved json back as list
       List<Data> dataList= gson.fromJson(reader , token.getType()); 
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Alright, all done hope this is enough for your implementation.